# SSRS Sum Averages

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report where I am calculating the average by the department. However, I also want to calculate the total average per month and grand total average as follows. If I do any averages in these groups it will not calculate the desired value.

[image]

Thanks, Greg

Comment: I'm not sure where the 1468.5 and 1473 come from? Is the image what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Whoops, it should have been 105.5 + 118.5. The data had been updated after I wrote the description...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you want to get to is what you have shown in the image then you should just be able to do something like..

```
=Sum(Fields!MyAmountField.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!MyMonthField.Value)
```

If there is any more grouping than you actually show then you may need to define the scope of the calculation by adding the scope name (probably the name of your parent row group or tablix name), something like this.

```
=Sum(Fields!MyAmountField.Value, "myScopeName") / CountDistinct(Fields!MyMonthField.Value, "myScopeName")
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't illustrated that the Departments are grouped (For example department 1 consists of 2 rows, Row 1 = 6, Row 2 = 4. So the average is 5.). So if I did the total and divided by count it would average out across all departments. I need the total of all departments averages.

Comment: Could you mick up some data as it comes from your dataset along with the expected results of the mock data so I can replicate your scenario.

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction and I believe I have now resolved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Great. You should probably post how you resolved it if my answer was not complete so that others will find it useful in the future.